# How to change the default values for new DNS zone?

Tags: windows-registry, dns-zone

How we can change (or set) the default values for the new DNS zone records?
When we make a new Zone from its wizard in Microst DNS server, there is no question about the "name servers", then only the primary name server is added in the "Name Servers" tab of the zone properties.(e.g TEST.COM in attched image)

Where is the location of these parameters in registry? I want to set values of  "name servers" so when I make a new record, It will have all of needed NS server names and IP addresses by default.

[zone properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VHfWS.png)

Comment: Are you  creating forward lookup zones? If yes,Microsoft DNS server should  prompt you to choose on Zone types. When you create the zone right click on properties then click on Name servers,here you can add all the name severs that can be queried for the domain records.

Comment: @Peter: Thank you for your comment.  I tried to clear the question. I hope I can said what is in my mind

Answer (score 0):

I'm not understanding this question. When you create a new primary DNS zone, the server you are creating it on is the primary server. When you create a new secondary DNS zone, the server you are creating it on is the secondary server. You specify the primary server when you create the secondary zone, so this information comes from *you*.

The responsible person is always hostmaster.DnsSuffix, where DnsSuffix is the primary DNS suffix of the server that you created the primary zone on.

`I want to set the "name servers" so when I make a new record, It will have all of needed NS server names and IP addresses by default` - I don't understand that statement. You don't specify the name servers when you create a record in the zone.

Comment: He was maybe thinking DHCP??

Comment: @guntbert since you mentioned that, I think it's quite possible ...

Comment: @all: I tried to clear my question. I think there is a way to set the "name servers" default value for any new zone.